Apache-poi, jxls-poi version compatible
I have a question regarding java excel.
I updated the Apache-poi version from 3.17 to 4.1.2, but excel download does not work.
And since the existing jxls-core was transferred to org.jxls, jxls-core was removed and the jxls version was updated to 2.10.0.
This is the related code
pom.xml
<dependency> 
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls-poi</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

code
public void download(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Map<String, Object> beans, String filename, String templateFile) {
            InputStream is = null;
            OutputStream os = null;
            try {
                Resources.setCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                is = new BufferedInputStream(Resources.getResourceAsStream("excel_templates/" + templateFile));
                PoiTransformer transformer = PoiTransformer.createTransformer(is);

                // Map을 Context 객체로 변환
                Context context = new Context(beans);
                JxlsHelper.getInstance().processTemplate(context, transformer);
                Workbook resultWorkbook = transformer.getWorkbook();

                // 응답 헤더 및 Content-Type 설정
                response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + ".xlsx\"");

                // OutputStream 초기화
                os = response.getOutputStream();

                // 워크북을 OutputStream에 씀
                resultWorkbook.write(os);
                os.flush(); // 버퍼 비우기
                System.out.println("10");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error during download: " + e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                // 자원 정리
                try {
                    if (is != null) is.close();
                    if (os != null) os.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    logger.error("Error closing streams: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }

2024-10-07 16:27:09.764 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] ERROR com.sgt.appm.excel.MakeExcel - Error during download: Cannot write a workbook with an uninitialized output stream
remove dependencies
 <dependency>
         <groupId>net.sf.jxls</groupId>
         <artifactId>jxls-core</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.6</version>
   </dependency> 

      public void download(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Map<String , Object> beans, String filename, String templateFile) {
                try { 
                        Resources.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(Resources.getResourceAsStream("excel_templates/" + templateFile));
                        XLSTransformer transformer = new XLSTransformer();
                        Workbook resultWorkbook = transformer.transformXLS(is, beans);
                        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + ".xlsx\"");
                        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
                        resultWorkbook.write(os);
                        is.close();
                        resultWorkbook.close(); 
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        logger.error(e.getMessage());
                }
        }


Will it work if you use: FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("output.xlsx"); instead the one from the response?
